# Parameterize a value to function inside the same class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to insert a data inside my `log_tb` table using the `set_log()` method inside the `User_model` class. But I can't seem to make it work, thinking because of the way I parameterize a user id to `set_log()` (*No error are showing even though I set the `$config['log_threshold']` to `4` in the config.php*).

User id comes from a query from `get_user` method and run through the result using `foreach()` to get the user id.

Take a look at my class below:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function set_log($userid) /* INSERT METHOD */
    {
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); /* GET THE DATE AND TIME */

        $data = array(
            'user_id' => $userid,
            'log_date' => $date
        );

        return $this->db->insert('log_tb', $data); /* INSERT THE DATA TO log_tb */
    }

    public function get_user($pinno = FALSE)
    {
        if ($pinno === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('user_tb');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('user_tb', array('pin_no' => $pinno));

        foreach($query->result() as $query_item) /* RUN THROUGH THE RESULT */
        {
            $this->User_model->set_log($query_item["user_id"]); /* GET THE USER ID AND PARAMETERIZE IT TO set_log METHOD */
        }

        return $query->row_array();

    }

}
```

How can I get the user id from `$query` variable to make it as a parameter to `set_log()` method? Is this the right approach to this type of logic? Or should I just call the `set_log()` outside?

Comment: i think this line `foreach($query->result() as $query_item)` should be `foreach($query->result_array() as $query_item)`

Comment: @devpro - thanks! That is right, sintakonte below already answered it. :)

Comment: yes @sintakonte is the king... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you use $query->result the outcome is an object try this

```
public function get_user($pinno = FALSE)
{
    if ($pinno === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('user_tb');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('user_tb', array('pin_no' => $pinno));

    foreach($query->result_array() as $query_item) /* RUN THROUGH THE RESULT */
    {
        $this->set_log($query_item['user_id']); /* GET THE USER ID AND PARAMETERIZE IT TO set_log METHOD */
    }

    return $query->result_array();

}
```

Comment: You got it! Still trying to understand codeigniter. So looks like I'll be posting a lot of question like this. BTW, is my approach right to this type of problem?

Comment: if you are a starter it looks really fine - nothing wrong about it
maybe you can extract your log function into a separate Log Model to abstract a bit more but for now its fine

Comment: If I put it in a separate model, (i.e. `Log_model`), how will I be able to call the `set_log()` method inside the `get_user()` method? Thanks again!

Comment: in your get_user function put on the top $this->load->model("Log_Model");
and instead of $this->set_log use $this->Log_Model->set_log();

Comment: `insert_batch()` method would be less expensive. [Docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data).

Comment: you can also write a post system hook who handles all the logging in a bulk method in order to get optimized speed - but hey he is a beginner @CI - baby steps are more important than anything else ;)

Comment: Correct, but defacto `insert_batch()` method is baby step itself. All can be find on same page which I have linked. In plausable case where there are many `pin_no` rows, it avoids doubling DB connection. I don't think your answer is wrong, I am just helping to improve answer for @GrandMarshalBraev application sake.

Answer (score 1):

In this function `get_user()` you are using `$query->result()` for getting userid as `$query_item["user_id"]`, it will return you result in object form not in array.

**Modified Function:**

```
public function get_user($pinno = FALSE)
{
    if ($pinno === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('user_tb');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('user_tb', array('pin_no' => $pinno));

    foreach($query->result() as $query_item) /* RUN THROUGH THE RESULT */
    {
        $this->User_model->set_log($query_item->user_id); /* GET THE USER ID AND PARAMETERIZE IT TO set_log METHOD */
    }

    return $query->row_array();

}
```

---

There are two solutions:

**Solution 1:**

If you want to use

```
$query->result()
```

Than you need to use userid like:

```
$query_item->user_id // as property in foreach() body
```

**Solution 2:**

If you want to use

```
$query->result_array()
```

Than no need to change anything in `foreach()` body:

```
$query_item["user_id"] // as array index
```

Comment: This is also correct. But I have to remove `User_model` in `$this->User_model->set_log(...)` to make it work. But I thought it would still work  by still calling the class. Don't know why.

Comment: @GrandMarshalBraev: also check your `autoload.php` file